# Math.pow(-27.0,1.0/3) returns NaN

Tags: java, pow

`Math.pow(-27.0, 1.0/3)` should be equivalent to `cbrt(-27)` which *does* return -3. Why does `pow` return `NaN`?

It is not integer division and it is not me, I can not think of a reason this should happen.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)), one of the special cases for `Math.pow(double,double)` method is:

> If the first argument is finite and less than zero and the second
>   argument is finite and not an integer, then the result is NaN.

And [Math.cbrt(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cbrt(double)) works because:

> For positive finite x, cbrt(-x) == -cbrt(x); that is, the cube root of
>   a negative value is the negative of the cube root of that value's
>   magnitude

Comment: Thank you, I did a local fix by seperating it into the negitive and the number then tacking the negitive on as text, sorry for spelling, in a rush

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't return an error. I highly recommend you read through the *rules* given in the [`Math.pow(double, double)` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-). I'll help *the first argument is finite and less than zero* **and** *the second argument is finite and not an integer, then the result is NaN.*

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take the cube root of -27 rationally because it is negative, which explains why math.pow returns NAN.  Cbrt(-27) returns -3 because it works a little differently: it takes the magnitude of the value (in this case, ||-27|| = 27), calculates and then reapplies the negative, giving you -3.